# Find one series solution for $xy'' - y = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

I have found the recurrence relation to be $a_{n+1} = \frac{(a_n)}{(n+1)(n)}$ . I am stuck at this part because no matter what I set the initial a to be, the following term will have a problem due to division by 0. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Try with a very few terms (say $3$) and identify. You will find $a(0)=0$, $a(2)=a(1)/2$ and your recurrence relation which is correct.

Now remember that, if you multiply a function by a constante, its second derivative is multiplied by the same consatant. So, you can keep $a(1)$ or assign any value to it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand why I am allowed to assign an arbitrary value to a(1).

Comment: @ahn. Because a(1) is undefined but all other coefficients depend on a(1). So, do not worry, just keep $a(1)$ which could be fixed by any boundary condition.

Comment: @ahn.You welcome. Glad to have helped. Cheers.

Comment: How do we get $a_0$ here? In Frobenius method, don't we always take $a_0 \neq 0$?