# Solving DE $\ tx''-x=0$ via power series.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following equation

> $$tx''-x=0$$

which I want to solve via power series.

I get it in "standard" form to apply Frobenious method. My initial equation becomes

$r(r-1)$.

After equating coefficents I get

$a_{n-1}=\dfrac{a_{n-2}}{n(n-1)} $ in front of $t^{n}$. For $n\ge 1$ and $a_{0}$ arbitrary. However according to the book it should be $a_{1} \sum_{k\ge 1}\dfrac{t^{k}}{k!(k-1)!}$.

I've done it three times. Can anyone get this right?

The duplicate does not accomodate my troubles, my problem was about renamning coefficents. The second possible duplicate is closer, but still not the same.

Comment: Are you sure about your equation ? You can easily see that the solutions of this equation are functions like $ t \mapsto Ct$ where $C$ is a constant.

Comment: As far as I know Frobenious method apply for second order DEs.

Comment: @tmaths fixed!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$xy''-y=0$ with initial conditions $y(0)=0$ and $y'(0)=1$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2850327/xy-y-0-with-initial-conditions-y0-0-and-y0-1)

Comment: Also see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/651657/find-one-series-solution-for-xy-y-0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is correct, as is the one in the book. For the root $r=1$, with your notation, the solution is
$$
t\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\,t^n=a_0\,t+a_1\,t^2+\dots.
$$
What the book is doing is renaming $a_0\to a_1$, $a_1\to a_2$, ... and looking for solution of the form
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\,t^n.
$$

Comment: Hmm is that reasonable on thier part? You cant just rename coefficent willy nilly. In particular when the algorithms invovle playing around with them. Or do you know a reasonable explation for this?

Comment: It is perfectly reasonable. They chose to match the subindex with the exponent. The solution is the same. Think of it this way. The book gives the solution as $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_nt^n$ and $a_0=b_1$, $a_1=b_2$, ...